# Get oauth2 token using rest assured Java client

Tags: java, user-interface, soap, rest-assured

How to get oauth2 token from the end point, at present I am getting the token from soap ui tool but I have Java framework which uses rest assured for automating rest/soap requests. In soap ui tool we achieve this as mentioned in the following link:
https://www.soapui.org/oauth2/oauth2-authorization.html

Please help me to get the code.

Comment: Read the documentation. https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#oauth There are sections specifically on oauth2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew. The document is not helping out for me as I have 3 different URLs i.e. Authorisation URL, access token URL and redirect URL and scope. When I click on get access token in soap ui it opens a web page where in I need to provide login ID and password to get the token. I am not sure how we can achieve that using rest-assured. Please suggest.

Comment: Sounds like its going to be difficult if you cannot get oauth token through api endpoint. You can send log in credentials as a form. https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#authentication . Not sure how you would extract the token without seeing the response after log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to pass the secret token embedded inside the response, which resolved my issue.